# What is the problem with this SELECT query?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT   Ticket_no, journey_date, Travels, route, sel_seat, 
         seat_opt, net_pay, name, mob, book_date, PNR_no 
FROM     a1_ticket 
WHERE    (CONVERT, GETDATE(),'-') AS [DD-Mon-YYYY], journey_date) >=journey_date1 
  AND    (CONVERT, GETDATE(),'-') AS [DD-Mon-YYYY], journey_date) <=journey_date2  
ORDER BY PNR_no DESC
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? It seems to me like there are some serious syntax errors, especially near the parts where you try to use `CONVERT`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AS in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause is weird. Perhaps you want something like this instead.

```
SELECT   Ticket_no, journey_date, Travels, route, sel_seat, 
         seat_opt, net_pay, name, mob, book_date, PNR_no 
FROM     a1_ticket 
WHERE    journey_date between @journey_date1 and @journey_date2  
ORDER BY PNR_no DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is `journey_date1` and `journey_date2` really in the same record? It would be very strange. Otherwise, parameters/variables use the @ symbol, e.g. `@journey_date1`
2. [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) syntax should be `CONVERT(<target type>, <column|expression>, <optional format>)`
3. Don't convert the columns of the table. Instead, always convert the parameters being tested against the date to make use of indexes
4. No conversion is necessary for datetime parameters compared against datetime columns. To specify date literals, for robustness always use `YYYYMMDD` but if possible at all, use parameterized queries from the front end, which won't even need any formatting.

It looks like your query should be something like this

```
SELECT   Ticket_no, journey_date, Travels, route, sel_seat, 
         seat_opt, net_pay, name, mob, book_date, PNR_no 
FROM     a1_ticket 
WHERE    journey_date >= @journey_date1 
  AND    journey_date <= @journey_date2  
ORDER BY PNR_no DESC
```